# How to connect to wss socket where host name has additional path using NSStream?

Tags: ios, sockets, wss, nsstream, nsinputstream

I'm trying to connect to wss socket, and the host name looks like this: "myhostname.com/ws/v2".
Here is how I start the connection:

```
let host = "myhostname.com/ws/v2"

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host as CFString, 443, &readStream, &writeStream)

inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

outputStream.setProperty(StreamSocketSecurityLevel.negotiatedSSL, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.socketSecurityLevelKey)
inputStream.setProperty(StreamSocketSecurityLevel.negotiatedSSL, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.socketSecurityLevelKey)

inputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
outputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .commonModes)

inputStream.delegate = self
outputStream.delegate = self

inputStream.open()
outputStream.open()
```

This fails with an error:
`The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)`

However, if I remove the path from the host name, so it looks like this: `myhostname.com` then in my delegate I get an event `openCompleted`. However, it doesn't respond to my messages after that, I assume it's because I'm connected to a wrong socket, since I removed the path.

What is the proper way of connecting to a socket when the host name has an additional path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myhostname.com/ws/v2` is not a hostname.  It is an (incomplete) URL (the complete URL is `wss://myhostname.com/ws/v2`).  The hostname is just `myhostname.com`, and the Websocket path on that host is just `/ws/v2`.

The WebSockets handshake uses HTTP/S, so it is not enough to just connect to the host with an `NSStream`.  You have to connect a TCP socket to the `host` and port, then negotiate an SSL/TLS handshake if using WSS, then use HTTP to request the `path` asking for an `Upgrade` to WebSocket, and only if a successful HTTP `101` reply is returned then perform the WebSocket handshake.

That is a lot of work to do manually.  You really should be using an actual WebSocket client library instead.  There are plenty available.